# How to duplicate part of html code in django using jinja2?

Tags: python, django, jinja2

I need to duplicate a certain part of the code through the Django admin panel. But I do not know how this can be implemented. My teacher suggested that this can be done through jinja2, but I don't really understand how to use jinja2 for my purposes. I would be very grateful to anyone who can help either find information or show you how to implement it.
this is the html code that needs to be duplicated

```html
<td class ="sale">
         {% if good.image %}
        <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ good.image_sale }}">
        {% endif %}
      {% for good in goods %}
        <h1 class="description">{{ good.description_text }}</h1>
      {% endfor %}
  <a class="buy" href="#openModal" >
    <span >Купить</span></a>
  {% for good in goods %}
        <h1 class="price" >{{ good.price_text }}</h1>
  {% endfor %}
  </td>
```

I do not know what else to add, if you need something else, write, I will add

Comment: I would simply use `Ctrl+C` `Ctrl+V` to duplicate code. I don't understand what you want to do.

Comment: I don't understand your code - I would use only one `for`-loop for `goods` - and inside this single loop I would use `good.image` , `good.description_text`, `good.price_text`. At this moment you first put `good.image` but you don't have variable `good` in this moment. And later you put all descriptions, and later all prices .